# Default Makefile location?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Both in the [CS50 Lecture 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9Eds2Rc_x8) and this [old CS50 GDB video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCtY--xRUyI) they use `make` without any `makefile` present beforehand and it calls `clang` with several arguments. However when I run `make` it seems to use `cc`.

I figured that this had to have meant that there is a default `makefile` being used whenever I ran `make`. I checked the `make` documents and couldn't find anything to support my theory. However there is a line in the [online document](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefile-Arguments) for GNU `make`:

> If you do not use the `‘-f’` or `‘--file’` flag, the default is to try `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and `Makefile`, in that order, and use the first of these three which exists or can be made.

At the end of that it directs me to another section that says:

> If `make` finds none of these names, it does not use any makefile. Then you must specify a goal with a command argument, and `make` will attempt to figure out how to remake it using only its built-in implicit rules.

Here are screenshot examples of both videos:
[image: CS50 Lecture 1]

[image: old CS50 GDB video]

Is this something that `make` is able to do?

Comment: Have a read about [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Implicit-Rules) -- that should provide a lot of information about what `make` does in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Make has a number of built-in rules, that use a number of default variables, that are used if no makefile exists (or if a makefile does exist but doesn't override these built-in rules or variables with different ones).

However, the built-in defaults are always to use `cc` for a C compiler and there are no flags at all provided to the compiler except for the basic `-o` and `-c`.

However, the value of these default variables can be overridden by environment variables.  So, if it's really the case that there is no makefile present but yet these extra flags are being used, it's possible they have defined some environment variables such as:

```
export CC=clang
export CFLAGS='....'
```

(I couldn't copy and paste flags from your screenshot and I didn't feel like retyping so you'll have to imagine them).

Also, be aware they could have set the [`MAKEFILES` environment variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/MAKEFILES-Variable.html) to point to a makefile or set of makefiles, that will be read even if no local makefile exists.